# Which source module in Yahoo pipes is most suitable for feeding data to a Yahoo filter?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I have a file, se [Google doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AstJzCCxOXH1dHllMVlVVjFOaVZHdTFvQTQ5aE9HSUE), with 20+ RSS feeds. I want to use Yahoo pipes for searching for specific strings in these feeds.

In the Yahoo pipe editor, there are a number of modules for "Sources", see [Yahoo Pipes Source Modules](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=sources).

The modules are:

1. Feed Auto-Discovery Module
2. Fetch CSV Module
3. Fetch Data Module

   Fetch Feed Module

   Find First Site Feed (was Fetch Site Feed) Module

   Flickr Module

   Item Builder Module

   Yahoo! Local Module

   Fetch Page Module (deprecated)

   XPATH Fetch Page Module

I have tried the "Fetch Feed Module" and it can only contain 10 feeds.

**Which one of these modules should I use when I have more than 20 RSS feeds?** The answer could also be that "Use .. instead of Yahoo pipes".

The output is to be feed to a filter module.

Comment: Use a union of two fetch feeds.

Comment: I understand that, what I would like to have is the RSS feeds in a separate document and have Yahoo pipes read that document. If I use the Fetch Feed module, I have to "hardwire" the actual RSS URL:s

Comment: Fredrik, put a CSV file with feed URLs somewhere on the 'Net. Use Fetch CSV, Loop (with Fetch Feed inside) to combine stuff. I remember doing something like that a while ago, but I'm not sure if I was actually happy with the result.

Comment: ok, I will try that. Put it to an answer :-)

Comment: Done............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is as follows:

1. **Fetch CSV** (actually, in my case I found it easier to have "|" as separators) hosted on an external site

   - Columns separated by "|"
   - Use the following column names: "feed", "link"
2. (optional) **Filter** (to get only items that are needed in this particular set of circumstances.
3. **Loop**

   - For each `item` in input feed
   - **Fetch Feed**
   - `item.link`
   - Assign all results to `item.loop`
4. **Sub-Element**

   - `item.loop`
5. (optional) **Filter** (to weed out what's not necessary)
6. (Whatever other items needed - renaming, regexing, filtering, truncating)

In case of large sub-feeds, I suggest creating a separate pipe to truncate a feed to manageable number of elements and to avoid hitting the Yahoo! upper limit.

Comment: Great, will try it and then accept it. Do you know the upper limit?

Comment: @FredrikD - there is something on "acceptable use policy" on the site... In my practice, it could be determined through experimentation.